# Having problem getting user by id on endpoints, could someone look at my code and maybe guide me?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite, endpoint

So what I am trying to do here is get user by id and then show it but seems like my knowledge is lacking and would be happy if someone could point out the mistakes! Code below:

```
    //routes.js
    const routes = require('express').Router();
    const dbService = require('./database');
    
    routes.get('/products', async (req,res) => {
        try {
            const resultat = await dbService.getProducts();
            res.json(resultat)
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    routes.get('/user/:id', async (req,res) => {
        try 
        {
            const id = req.params.id
            const user = await dbService.getUserId(id);
            
            res.send(user);
            console.log(user);
            
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            res.send('error..');
        }
    });
//database.js
const getUserId = async (data) => {
    try
    {
        const dbCon = await dbPromise;
        const user =  dbCon.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (?)', [data.id]);
        return user;
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you give more details on your problem and point what doesn't work as intended?

Comment: I think the error is in database.js. Try this `const user =  dbCon.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (?)', [data]);`

Comment: sure, Im sorry I rarely use stackoverflow so I might not be good at asking help, but when I use Postman, and write in my url "http://localhost:3000/api/user/1" I want it to give the info about the user who has the ID with 1. I hope that answers your question!

Comment: @patriktorkildsen thank you sooo much!! I was pulling my hair for hours, thanks a lot! :D